# MongoDB insufficient journal space after adding --smallfiles

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, cloud9

Added `--smallfiles` into **my config** and still to no avail. I get the same error, and cannot seem to get my mongodb up and running.(I am currently working in cloud 9).

```
2017-04-20T06:10:59.027+0000 [initandlisten] ERROR: Insufficient free space for journal files
2017-04-20T06:10:59.027+0000 [initandlisten] Please make at least 3379MB available in /data/db/journal or use --smallfiles
```

[Picture of the mongodb file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Abf57.png)

Comment: FYI, this question is more on-topic for DBA StackExchange than StackOverflow. What are your versions of MongoDB and O/S? How much free space do you have in your `dbpath`? The `--smallfiles` option only applies to the MMAP storage engine and initial data/journal file allocation. If you are low on free space and plan to add or update data, I would consider adding more disk space rather than trying to get MongoDB running with a slim margin of free space.

Comment: Alternatively you could consider using the WiredTiger storage engine (MongoDB 3.0+) which has data & index compression enabled by default and makes more efficient use of disk space.

Comment: @Stennie Thanks, ill remember next time I need another question like this answered. I did end up figuring it out, thank you again!